# Does the order of Appengine DataStore query conditions matter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I must be missing something here, but this is a problem I can't seem to understand.

In the datastore, there is 1 record
    proj_id= u'1', type ='normal'

This (correctly) returns None.

```
delete_keys = self.query(self.proj_id == u'2').fetch(keys_only=True)
```

This (correctly) returns the one record from the datastore.

```
delete_keys = self.query(self.type == 'normal').fetch(keys_only=True)
```

This (correctly) returns None.

```
delete_keys = self.query(self.type == 'normal' and self.proj_id == u'2').fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Yet, strangely, this returns the one record from the datastore, instead of None.

```
delete_keys = self.query(self.proj_id == u'2' and self.type == 'normal').fetch(keys_only=True)
```

It seems like the order of query conditions matter. But why & how? Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine conditions with 'and' like that, you should pass them as separate arguments to `query`:

```
delete_keys = self.query(self.type == 'normal', self.proj_id == u'2').fetch(keys_only=True)
```

The behaviour you're seeing is due to how 'and' works in python:

The result of `x and y` is `x` if `x` is falsey, otherwise it is `y`.

The FilterNode returned by the equality operator (the result of `self.type == 'normal'`) isn't falsey, so the result of `self.type == 'normal' and self.proj_id == u'2'` is just `self.proj_id == u'2'` - the query is only being passed one condition, and so the queries being performed in your 3rd and 4th code-blocks are exactly the same as in 1 and 2.

Comment: You can also use the ndb query AND operator  `ndb.AND(self.type == 'normal',self.proj_id == u'2')`